# Save image to internal storage using ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(). - (Kotlin/Java/Android)

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-camera, internal-storage

I'm new to file storage. My main goal is to take a picture with the camera, store it with good quality, then display it in an ImageView. I want to avoid asking for user permission (to use camera and external storage), and want to make this as simple as possible.

To take a picture, I'm using

`val capturePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { it: Boolean -> }`.
I don't know how to get the bitmap from this function or if I should. To my understanding I should send the uri when calling `capturePicture.launch(uri)`.

My question is if this is correct, also how do I get the URI, save it to internal storage (`.openFileOutput()`), then load it from internal storage.

I prefer the answer in Kotlin but Java is fine too.
An explanation on how paths work in internal storage could be helpful too.

Comment: https://medium.com/codex/how-to-use-the-android-activity-result-api-for-selecting-and-taking-images-5dbcc3e6324b -- that post shows how to use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` pointing to some file that you control, then use it with `TakePicture()` to attempt to take a picture with the user's chosen camera app. The resulting image will already be on internal storage, and you can use your favorite image-loading library (Glide, Coil, Picasso, etc.) to populate your `ImageView`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed this [medium article](https://medium.com/codex/how-to-use-the-android-activity-result-api-for-selecting-and-taking-images-5dbcc3e6324b) tutorial, adjusted it and added more functionality for my use case.

Saved images in the cache directory

To take the picture:

```
private val takeImageResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSuccess ->
        if (isSuccess) {
            latestTmpUri?.let { uri ->
                loadPhotosFromInternalStorageIntoRecyclerView()
            }
        }
    }
```

To call take picture, save it, and get the uri:

```
private var latestTmpUri: Uri? = null
private fun takeImage() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        getTmpFileUri().let { uri ->
            latestTmpUri = uri
            takeImageResult.launch(uri)
        }
    }
}
private fun getTmpFileUri(): Uri {
    val tmpFile = File.createTempFile("tmp_image_file", ".jpg", requireActivity().cacheDir).apply {
        createNewFile()
        deleteOnExit()
    }
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity().applicationContext, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", tmpFile)
}
```

To load the picture (loads the first picture in the list of pictures):

```
private fun loadPhotosFromInternalStorage(): List<InternalStoragePhoto> {
    val files = requireActivity().cacheDir.listFiles()
    return files?.filter {
        it.canRead() && it.isFile && it.name.endsWith(".jpg")
    }?.map {
        InternalStoragePhoto(it.name, it.toUri())
    } ?: listOf()
}
private fun displayImage() {
    Glide.with(photoImg.context)
        .load(loadPhotosFromInternalStorage()[0].uri)
        .into(photoImg)
}
```

Here's the custom object for the images:

```
data class InternalStoragePhoto(
    val name: String,
    val uri: Uri?
)
```

This is a simplified version of my code, here's the source code for the test app [github repo](https://github.com/edcres/test-apps/blob/master/with-hardware-plus/app/src/main/java/com/example/testhardwareplus/internalstore/InternalStoreFragment.kt)